# Using iCal to update and remove calendar items

Tags: updates, icalendar

I have a web app that has its own calendar system. I want to send email notifications to users when they add / update / remove calendar events.

I am using iCal via a nuget package Ical.Net to create the event attachments. This works great when adding a new calendar event. I am able to get the email with the iCal attachment and accept it and it adds it to my google calendar.

The question I have is this: Is there a way using iCal to send an Update or Remove type object that will affect the previously added calendar event?

I tried using the same Uid in the second iCal object, but that didn't work.

Update: This is the meeting creation stream:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 2.2//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:hi
DTEND:20171019T200000
DTSTAMP:20171018T022927Z
DTSTART:20171019T193000
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:Confirmed
SUMMARY:test
UID:2291d1c2-3b6d-404a-82ac-16807ecfd580
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The Update stream is the same with just different start and end times.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have read a lot of posts and the RFC 2446 to try to get this right and am still having trouble. Here are my 3 examples for the original item, an update to change the date and then a cancel. I end up with a single event only at the original time. It doesn't change the time with the update and it doesn't cancel the event.

I also tried putting the METHOD: line inside the VEVENT because I thought I read that would work when reading the RFC 2446. when I did that I ended up with 3 events. The original and 2 at the new date.

**Initial event**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//RealtimeMD//Medical Portal//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20171020T023000Z
DTEND:20171020T030000Z
DTSTAMP:20171020T015303Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Bob Docter:mailto:drbob@shatalmic.com
UID:24258c34-2888-43ec-ac3d-180ee2603294
CREATED:20171020T015303Z
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
LAST-MODIFIED:20171020T015304Z
LOCATION:RealtimeMD Zoom
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:t
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**Update Event**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//RealtimeMD//Medical Portal//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20171021T023000Z
DTEND:20171021T030000Z
DTSTAMP:20171020T015303Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Bob Docter:mailto:drbob@shatalmic.com
UID:24258c34-2888-43ec-ac3d-180ee2603294
CREATED:20171020T015303Z
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
LAST-MODIFIED:20171020T015340Z
LOCATION:RealtimeMD Zoom
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:t
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**Cancel event**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//RealtimeMD//Medical Portal//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20171021T023000Z
DTEND:20171021T030000Z
DTSTAMP:20171020T015303Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Bob Docter:mailto:drbob@shatalmic.com
UID:24258c34-2888-43ec-ac3d-180ee2603294
CREATED:20171020T015303Z
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
LAST-MODIFIED:20171020T015433Z
LOCATION:RealtimeMD Zoom
SEQUENCE:2
STATUS:CANCELLED
SUMMARY:t
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Please provide both the icalendar stream corresponding to the add and update in your description

Comment: I was looking in the library I am using to create the iCal item and saw that I can change the status. You will notice in the example I updated I set the status to Confirmed. I tried changing that to Cancelled, but that doesn't remove the item like I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending those over email, you want to send an iTIP message with a PUBLISH method as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.1 . This has also implication on how you construct your email message. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6047

Comment: Would you mind going into more detail? The main thing I saw is that the Organizer must be present for the cancel or updates to the event to work. Is that the only thing I am missing or are there other things?

Comment: Regarding the e-mail constraints Arnaud mentioned above: I don't mean to advocate non-standard or incomplete implementations, but... In my limited experience with a few major proprietary iCal implementations, [1998 iTIP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2446) has been sufficient for interoperability, and avoiding [2010 iMIP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6047#section-2.4) by not including a `METHOD` parameter in the `content-type` field as mentioned in the iMIP RFC has simplified my implementation. It appears it was intended to support simpler, legacy implementations